# app.get not defined when calling a separate .js file node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the app.js file:

```
var cluster = require("cluster");
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  var cpuCount = require("os").cpus().length;
  for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  cluster.on("exit", function() {
    console.log("A cluster died\n A cluster was created!");
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  var bcrypt = require("bcrypt"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    express = require("express"),
    session = require("express-session"),
    isemail = require("isemail"),
    nodemailer = require("nodemailer"),
    path = require("path"),
    r = require("rethinkdbdash")({
      port: 28015,
      host: "localhost",
      db: "FPC"
    }),
    socket = require("socket.io");
  var app = express();
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  var login = require(path.join(__dirname + "/config/login.js"));
}
```

Here is the config/login.js file

```
app.get('/login',function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/www/CreateAccount/index.html"));
});
```

When I try to launch the app it gives me an error

```
ReferenceError: app is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yeet\Documents\Projects\website\config\login.js:1:63)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yeet\Documents\Projects\website\app.js:29:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
```

I can't figure out why it won't just take var app = express from the app.js. And requiring all the needed modules to run this removes the purpose of making login.js it's own file

Comment: The variable is local to that module. You'll have to export or make it global.

Comment: You should look into how modules work in Node. [This](https://darrenderidder.github.io/talks/ModulePatterns/) looks like a reasonable starting point.